# How to programatically copy a table and specific row to paste in document later

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a document that contain a table that I have bookmarked and contain some text in square brackets that I use as placeholders.The second row of the table is also bookmarks and needs to be copied to add to the table depending on the number of rows required.

What I want to do is:-

1. Copy the table
2. Copy the second row of the table
3. Insert data from the first row of a Recordset1 into the first row of the table
4. Insert data in row 2 from recordset2.
5. If recordset2 contains multiple records paste the original version of row 2 with placeholders at the end of the table and add data
6. If recordset1 has more records paste the table at the end of the document and repeat steps 3 - 5

The problem that I am having is I don't know how to specify what I want the application to paste.

The codes that I am using are as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdPrintQuote_Click()

Dim strPath As String
Dim objquote As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rstLegs As Recordset
Dim rstPassengers As Recordset

strPath = 'code to select template

NewDocument strPath

'Create recordset for the legs associated with the quote

strSQL = SQL for recordset1

Set rstLegs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

rstLegs.MoveLast
rstLegs.MoveFirst

If rstLegs.RecordCount = 0 Then

    Exit Sub

ElseIf rstLegs.RecordCount > 1 Then

    CopyBookmarkedRange "PassengerSection" 'PassengerSection is the bookmark for row 2
    CopyBookmarkedRange "legtable" 'legtable is the bookmark for the entire table

    End If

Do Until rstLegs.EOF

    SelectEntireDocument

    'some code to insert data from recordset1 into row 1

    strSQL=SQL for recodset2

    Set rstPassengers = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    rstPassengers.MoveLast
    rstPassengers.MoveFirst

    If rstPassengers,RecordCount>0 then

        Do Until rstPassengers.EOF

            'some code to insert data from recordset2 into row 2

            rstPassengers.movenext

            If Not rstPassengers.EOF then

            'HELP Required Here
            'Code required to paste what was copied by CopyBookmarkedRange "PassengerSection" at the bottom of the table


            End If

        Loop

    End If

    rstLegs.MoveNext

    If Not rstLegs.EOF Then

        GotoDocEnd wdDoc
        InsertNewParagraph
        GotoDocEnd wdDoc
        wdApp.selection.paste

    End If

Loop

End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------

Public Function CopyBookmarkText(strBookmark As String)

CopyBookmarkText = wdDoc.Bookmarks(strBookmark).Range.Text

End Function

'-------------------------------------------------------

Public Function NewDocument(Optional strTemplatePath As String)

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") ' If word is already running getobject

If err.Number <> 0 Then 'Word isn't already running create object

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Open new document

If strTemplatePath <> "" Then

    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(strTemplatePath)

Else

    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

End If

wdApp.Visible = True 'Make application visible

End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function FindAndReplace(strFind As String, strReplacement As String, booWildCard As Boolean)

With wdApp.selection.Find

    .Text = strFind
    .Replacement.Text = strReplacement
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True

    If booWildCard = True Then
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Else
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End If

    .Execute Replace:=2             'NB:- Replace:=2 replaces all occurenece. To replace only 1 occurenece use Replace:=1

End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a workaround. The purpose of the code was to write the flight schedule of a multiple leg flight with the names of the passengers on each leg. Recordset1 for the legs and recordset2 for the passengers on each leg.The first 2 rows of the table have information about the leg and the remaining rows have information about the passengers.

My new approach was to

1. copy the entire table and paste the number of tables required for all the legs with bookmarks created programatically at the start and end of each table to indicate the leg number.
2. Run the recordsets to enter the data in each table using the bookmarks to select the which table to use.

The new codes are as follows:

```
'Create recordset for the legs

strSQL = SQL for recordset1

Set rstLegs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rstLegs.RecordCount = 0 Then

    Exit Sub

Else

    'Copy the table
    CopyBookmarkedRange "legtable"

    'Insert tables required for each leg

    For i = 2 To rstLegs.RecordCount

        GotoDocEnd wdDoc
        InsertNewParagraph
        GotoDocEnd wdDoc
        'Bookmark start of table for leg i
        wdDoc.bookmarks.Add name:="StartLeg" & i, range:=wdApp.selection.range
        wdApp.selection.paste
        GotoDocEnd wdDoc
        'Bookmark end of table for leg i
        wdDoc.bookmarks.Add name:="EndLeg" & i, range:=wdApp.selection.range

    Next i

End If

j = 1
'Now loop through recordset1
Do Until rstLegs.EOF
    'Select table based on leg number
    SelectLegRange (j)

    Run Code to input leg info in the table

    strSQL = "Select fldName,fldWeight,fldBaggage FROM qryPassengers WHERE " & strLegNumberCriteria

    Set rstPassengers = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    'Delete the last 3 rows of the table for that leg if there is no passengers and move to the next leg
    If rstPassengers.RecordCount = 0 Then

    SelectLegRange (j)

    For k = 0 To 2

    SelectLegRange (j)
    wdApp.selection.Tables(1).rows.last.select
    wdApp.selection.Tables(1).rows.last.range.cut

    Next k
    GoTo NextLeg

    End If

    rstPassengers.MoveLast
    rstPassengers.MoveFirst

    'Copy last row for pasting later if there more than one passenger on that leg
    If rstPassengers.RecordCount > 1 Then

        SelectLegRange (j)
        wdApp.selection.Tables(1).rows.last.select
        wdApp.selection.Tables(1).rows.last.range.copy

    End If

    run codes to input passenger info

    rstPassengers.MoveNext

    Do Until rstPassengers.EOF

        SelectLegRange (j)
        wdApp.selection.Tables(1).rows.last.select
        wdApp.selection.paste
        SelectLegRange (j)
        run codes to input passenger info

        rstPassengers.MoveNext

    Loop

NextLeg:
rstLegs.MoveNext
j = j + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to copy the table row, simply add rows to the table as needed.

```
For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    'Insert data into table
    objDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(idx).Range.Text = rs![Value]

    'If not last record, add new row
    If rs.AbsolutePosition <> rs.RecordCount - 1 Then
        objDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells.Add
    End If

    rs.MoveNext
Next idx
```

Also you dont have to use bookmarks, you can insert data directly to the table. Bookmark names must be unique so even if you copy the table row, bookmarks wont be copied; these will have to be added programmatically.

So, loop through the recordsets, insert data into the table, add rows as needed and repeat.

Comment: Thanks Kostas, your method would normally work but not in the current case because there are two recordsets.Second one nested in the first.

Comment: I dont see any issues. Just loop on both outer-inner and add rows as required.